# Classify web pages with neural net?

Tags: java, neural-network, nlp

So I am working on a java project and I'm have a webcrawler that retrieves and downloads the html from websites it finds. You input a word, such as the word Java, and my program then searches google for websites and downloads the html data.

So now I am trying to use a Neural Net to predict if the website is what I am looking for, yes I am aware that I am going to need a lot of data and have to manually feed the network. Where I am stuck is with converting the html into numbers for the neural net.

At first I though about just converting the html into plain text and then assign a number to each letter, and just have a document that is made up of a bunch of numbers that make up words. I am unsure though how a neural net would view this, would all these numbers be just one input or would each word be an input to the neural net, which then would cause the problem of having an unspecified number of inputs, and if the net allows this as one input would this be a viable way of classifying if a website is what I want or not?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am not familiar with Java, but most of the time you need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).   This means you have to provide some code, so we know how to help you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: I gotcha, its more of a conceptual question rather than a coding one hence not providing code, because their is no code to provide

Comment: Hey @DonC24, I have tried asking these conceptual questions, and most of the time(in my experience) they get downvoted/closed. Can you tell me what is it that you need to do?

Comment: Basically Im trying to figure out the best way to change html to where I can input it into a neural net that predicts if the website fits my criteria

Comment: Will this work? https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1998/AAAI98-073.pdf

Comment: Classifying HTML is a special case of classifying text. I would recommend you go through the [spaCy text categorization tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/training) and then figure out how to adapt that to HTML. Alternately, you might be able to just use the text from your web pages rather than the raw HTML.

Comment: Also as mentioned "conceptual questions" are generally considered not appropriate for Stack Overflow and closed for being too broad. You might have more luck on a forum for a neural network library like Pytorch.